# Accessing nested data with Angularfire

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am trying to capture changes to a nested array in my Firebase data. The data is laid out like so:

- **Calls**

  - **(Unique Firebase ID)**

    - Station: "Foobar"
    - Time: "20:30"

      - **Responders**

        - **(Unique Firebase ID)**

          - Name: "Frank"
          - Avatar: "foo.jpg"
        - **(Unique Firebase ID)**

          - Name: "Martha"
          - Avatar: "bar.jpg"

I need to keep track of when calls are changed and when responders are added or removed. What I am struggling with is tracking the responders to a call - I will not have the random IDs ahead of time, so I need to track in real time as calls and responders to each call change.

Here is what I have so far. Some code related to paths and getting a JWT is missing-

```
var ref = new Firebase('https://foobar.firebaseio.com/clients/' + clientAuth);
var callRef = ref.child('calls');
$scope.activeCalls = 0;
$scope.calls = $firebase(callRef);
$scope.calls.$on("change", function() {
            var keys = $scope.calls.$getIndex();
            $scope.activeCalls = keys.length;
            keys.forEach(function(key, i) {
                console.log($scope.calls[key].responders);
              // This provides an object with array of responders
            });
});
```

**UPDATE**

I remembered `child_added` from the regular Firebase.. came up with this. A more eloquent way would be appreciated, I am trying to keep this more Angular based.

```
$scope.calls.$on("child_added", function(v) {
            console.log(v.snapshot.value); // This gives me the details I need
        });
```

Comment: I don't really understand your goal here. The $firebase object you've created will automatically sync all changes to responders. You've asked for a more eloquent way but I'm having trouble understanding what's more eloquent than "automatic". I think some context may help here; this looks a bit like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). Also, check out [array best practices](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-04-28-best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html); generally you want to avoid these in distributed data.

Comment: I need to know when a responder is added or removed from a call and then modify elements in the DOM based on properties of the responder. For example, changing their listing as Available to being on that call. I also need to see which responders are on that call.

Comment: Also, I think I made it fairy clear what the problem is - difficulty obtaining the properties of a Responder object when it is added or removed from that Call. And when I list (Random ID) what I actually meant was unique ID, assigned by Firebase when I push the data.

Comment: I am still trying to figure out a solution to this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. It should not be this difficult to extract nested data.